# Get a Grunt plugin's target

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm building a Grunt plugin, and I need to select one of the targets in the `Gruntfile.js`.

Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    plugin: {
        options: {},
        target: {}  // <= This is what I want to select
    }
});
```

Inside of **tasks/plugin.js** I can use `options = this.options()` to get the `options` object, but I can't just use `this.target`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grunt only exposes `this.target` for [multi-tasks](http://gruntjs.com/inside-tasks#this.target).  To access the same value for regular tasks (*bar* in `grunt foo:bar`), access the [args array](http://gruntjs.com/inside-tasks#this.args) instead: `this.args[0]`

**Update:**

Previous answer was written according to the official terminology by Grunt.  Re-reading your question, you'll [access the property within the config object](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#accessing-config-data) using the `grunt.config()` method, drilling down to the specific properties you're trying to access within the grunt config object.  Based on your `grunt.initConfig` above, you'd access the contents of `target` with `grunt.config('plugin.target');`

Comment: I'm using `console.log(this.args[0])` which gives me `undefined`, and `console.log(this.args.length)` which gives me `0`.

Comment: `grunt.registerTask('default', ['plugin']);` <- That. I'm guessing you're going to say to run `plugin:target`, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: Answer updated, if that's not what you mean then I'll need you to clarify further.

Comment: That did the trick! I'm using `grunt.config(this.name + '.target');` to make it a little more maintainable. Thanks!